# wait for modules are loaded

Tags: requirejs

I have following code:

```
define([],
    function() {

        var AppSettings = function(){};
        AppSettings.prototype = {

            init: function() {
                var that = this;

                //...
                require(views,function(){
                    var counter = 0;
                    for(view in that.settings.initViews) {
                       that.initViews[view] = new arguments[counter++];
                    }
                    console.log("init");   
                });
            },

            run: function() {
                console.log("run");
            }

        };

        return AppSettings;
    }
);
```

And when I load AppSettings module:

```
require(["app_settings"],
    function(AppSettings) {
        var settings = new AppSettings();
        settings.init();
        setting.run();
    }
);
```

I get following output:

```
run
init
```

This is probably because I am loding modules async in init method - but how I can 'wait' for them to load? I mean how I can ensure that all async alls are done and then call `run`?